# Add-ADGroupMember Syntax

Tags: shell, powershell, active-directory

I don't understand what I do wrong:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership UserName | select name | where {$_.name -like "nac*"} | Add-ADGroupMember -Identity **$_.name**  -Members UserName
```

This is the error I get:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'.
>   The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then
>   try running the command again.

What should I put in the `$_.name`?

Comment: What do you want do accomplish? If you want to copy specific group memberships from one user to another then use add-adprincipalgroupmembership. In this case Identity is the new username.

Comment: I tried to get all the ADgroups from UserName that is named “NAC*” (only these) and add another user to all of these groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value stored in $Username be sure to include the $ character so PowerShell will recognize it as a variable. You also might want to remove the *s from the last cmdlet. This may not work as a one-liner. Try this:

```
$Group = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | select name | where {$_.name -eq "nac*"}

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.Name -Members $UserName
```

Comment: I tried that right now and i still get this error:

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

is $_.name ok?  Is this the right way to use it?

Comment: Try this, I'm not sure why $_.name is coming up $null...:
$Group = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | select name | where {$_.name -eq "nac*"}
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.Name -Members $UserName

I changed my answer to reflect this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$groups = get-adprincipalgroupmembership $sourceuser | ? Name -like "nac*"
#check content of $groups
$groups | select Name
add-adprincipalgroupmembership $targetuser -memberof $groups
```

I'm sure this will work. Otherwise please post your error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the `-Identity` parameter the cmdlets can handle:

The Identity parameter should be one of:

- A distinguished name (DN)
- A GUID,
- A security identifier (SID) or
- A Security Accounts Manager (SAM) account name

Both cmdlets also allow an object to be sent through the pipeline to the Identity parameter.

For `Add-ADGroupMember` this would be a group object.

For `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` you can use a user, group, or computer object.

This part of the code returns the group objects $UserName is a member of.
(remember: `$UserName` is the distinguished name, GUID, security identifier, or SAM account name of the user.)

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "nac*" }
```

Next you want to add a **different** user to the groups $UserName is a member of, right?

In that case, set up a variable to store the second user in, again use the distinguished name, 
GUID, security identifier, or SAM account name and then use something like this:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "nac*" } | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $AnotherUserToAddToThisGroup
```